# NGINX with "serverpool" as the LB for DIFFERENT DOMAINS on same Apache Servers?

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, domain, load-balancing, virtualhost

I have nginx as a LB. And the 2 Apaches as the web servers. Lets say i got different domains:

- www.example.com
- checkout.example.com

Both domains will be in same 2 Apache Servers. But ofcoz under the different directories. And with the different `VHost` files on the Apache vhost file.

As something like below design:

```
          Nginx
            |
      -------------
      |           |
   Apache       Apache
```

Below is my current existing Nginx .conf file which is not working for the second Domain (checkout.example.com).

From NGINX (mysites.conf):

```
upstream serverpool {
  server 1.2.3.101:80 weight=1;
  server 1.2.3.102:80 weight=1;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name www.example.com checkout.example.com;
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://serverpool;
  }
}
```

From both of 2 Apache Servers' **same** Vhost Files (httpd.conf):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName www.example.com
   DocumentRoot /var/www/html/www.example.com/
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName checkout.example.com
   DocumentRoot /var/www/html/checkout.example.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

But whenever i browse that (http://checkout.example.com), the **Domain still comes up** in browser .. **but with the contents of (www.example.com)**, which is totally wrong.

What did i do wrong please?

Comment: `proxy_set_header Host $host;`. See http://nginx.org/r/proxy_set_header

Comment: Where to put please? Or can you mentioned as in the answer, pls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should almost always set `Host` header. Otherwise nginx falls back to default `proxy_set_header Host $proxy_host;` which in your case would be `serverpool` which is useless for apache.

See http://nginx.org/r/proxy_set_header and http://nginx.org/r/proxy_pass for details.

```
upstream serverpool {
  server 1.2.3.101:80 weight=1;
  server 1.2.3.102:80 weight=1;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name www.example.com checkout.example.com;
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://serverpool;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you will need to send HOST: header to your upstream server IP's also

this artical is fully ansering to question

[Make nginx to pass hostname of the upstream when reverseproxying](https://serverfault.com/questions/598202/make-nginx-to-pass-hostname-of-the-upstream-when-reverseproxying)

also you nginx config should looks like this

```
    upstream serverpool {
  server 1.2.3.101:80 weight=1;
  server 1.2.3.102:80 weight=1;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name www.example.com checkout.example.com;
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://serverpool;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
  }
}
```