# Nginx proxy cookies not set

Tags: nginx, proxypass, cookies

Here's my situation, I have a Rails 4 app that can be accessed by multiple domains, depending on the domain, the content changes.

Say the main domain is `domain1` and all the other domains just use Nginx's `proxy_pass` to forward the requests to `domain1`, this is all working fine except that the session or other cookies are not set for `domain2`.

In my Rails app i've created a middleware that sets dynamically the `domain` for the session according to what domain is accessing the app using the content of the `CUSTOMHEADER` header, and I can see in the Set-Cookie header that the cookie domain is correct so I'm thinking my problem is in my Nginx configuration, but sadly my Nginx knowledge is quite limited.

**Nginx config**

The following is an example host file for `domain2` (one of the example domains where the cookies are not set):

```
server {
  listen   80;

  server_name domain2.com;
  rewrite ^(.*) http://www.domain2.com$1 permanent;
}

server {
  listen   80;
  server_name www.domain2.com;

  location /assets/ {
    proxy_pass                      https://main.domain1.com/assets/;
    proxy_set_header                X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header                X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header                Cookie $http_cookie;
    proxy_set_header                CUSTOMHEADER www.domain2.com;
    proxy_pass_request_headers      on;
  }

  location /some_path/ {
    proxy_pass                      https://main.domain1.com/some_path/;
    proxy_set_header                X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header                X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header                Cookie $http_cookie;
    proxy_set_header                CUSTOMHEADER www.domain2.com;
    proxy_pass_request_headers      on;
  }

  location / {
    proxy_pass                      https://main.domain1.com;
    proxy_set_header                X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header                X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header                Cookie $http_cookie;
    proxy_set_header                CUSTOMHEADER www.domain2.com;
    proxy_pass_request_headers      on;
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /sites/some-id/$1 break;
  }
}
```

when opening up a page in the browser and inspecting the headers i get the following (in Chrome):

**Response Headers**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.10.2
Date: Mon, 05 Nov 2018 22:21:45 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Status: 200 OK
Cache-Control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Request-Id: 33d26df0-f44c-4ff5-9513-62aaade8c581
ETag: W/"3dd8553b2a02cfc9f85a609c5f90bafb"
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Runtime: 0.025616
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Set-Cookie: _myapp_session=dmNFR2...3ae445b; domain=www.domain2.com; path=/; secure; HttpOnly
X-Powered-By: Phusion Passenger 5.1.2
Content-Encoding: gzip
```

**Request Headers**

```
GET /login HTTP/1.1
Host: www.domain2.com
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
Referer: http://www.domain2.com/bla
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,pt;q=0.8,fr;q=0.7
If-None-Match: W/"09c9ac3842dd3942a006b9000bd7a29d"
```

As you can see the Response contains the `Set-Cookie` header and the cookie has the correct domain, and yet the cookie is never set by the browser, and you will also notice that the Request doesn't have the `Cookie` header, although that might just be because there is no cookie to send.

**Note 1**: I've also tried setting the following headers in the response coming from the Rails app, but that didn't help:

- `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`
- `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true`

**Note 2**: I know the browser will not create the cookie if it's oversized but the cookie size should be far from the maximum, so I don't think that's the problem here.

The session works fine when accessing the main domain (`http://main.domain1.com`), what am I missing here? I feel like I'm lacking some theoretical knowledge about Nginx or web servers in general that is preventing me from getting this right but I've been struggling with this for 3 days, tried all kinds of headers and different combinations and so far all my research is fruitless.

Comment: Why are you using a CUSTOMHEADER: header, when the hostname is already available in the Host: header? You only need to [pass it upstream](https://serverfault.com/a/598269/126632). For that matter, why do you have separate `server` blocks? If it's the same web app and the same document root, all of the hostnames can be served from the same `server` block.

Comment: well the different hosts are user generated so whenever they create one, the app spits out all those configs in a separate file, makes it much easier to manage having that separation, as for the custom header, might not have been the best solution but it did the trick. But unless I'm wrong I don't think any of that relates to the cookie problem though, any thoughts on that?

Comment: Yes, but I already gave you the solution to that!  Use a single `server` block. Don't try to redirect.

Comment: not sure i understand, the first server block is just used to redirect to `www.domain2.com` in case the domain is accessed without the `www.`, not sure how removing that is gonna help with my problem.

Comment: No, I said nothing about that `server` block that redirects to https. It's all the duplicate ones that serve your web app that you need to have a single one.

Comment: So you're saying the `server` block for `main.domain1.com` and `www.domain2.com` should be merged? But how would that work? `domain2` paths map to different paths of `main.domain1.com` in some cases, as you can see in those `location` blocks, for example the the root of domain2 (`www.domain2.com/`) maps to `main.domain1.com/sites/some-id/`, would this be doable all in one `server` block?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally solved this, the problem was that the `main.domain1.com` was using SSL while the other domains weren't, I tried disabling SSL on the main domain and it worked, the other domains finally had session cookies, I'll have to see if it works once I add SSL to the other domains and re-enable it on the main domain but i'll cross that bridge once I get there.