# Make host header correct from upstream

Tags: windows, nginx, reverse-proxy

I configured simple load balancer scheme on the windows:

```
upstream app.local {
    server app1.local:8001 fail_timeout=10s max_fails=10;
    server app2.local:8002 fail_timeout=10s max_fails=10;
}

server {
    listen 8000;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://app.local;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    }
}
```

Changed hosts file like this

```
127.0.0.1       app.local
127.0.0.1       app1.local
127.0.0.1       app2.local
```

All fine, but my web servers behind app1.local and app2.local receive incorrect headers `Host: app.local` and therefore don't want resolve requests. I readed
[the post](https://serverfault.com/questions/598202/make-nginx-to-pass-hostname-of-the-upstream-when-reverseproxying) where the same problem but top answer not resolved my and i don't want to use the double layer proxy option straight off.

Comment: What were you expecting to happen?

Comment: @MichaelHampton I'm expecting that my http servers from upstream will receive correct host in header app1.local or app2.local. So they can resolve and process request. They are receiving app.local now.

Comment: You want Nginx to change the value of the Host header to whichever server is selected from the `upstream` block. Unfortunately, I don't think it's possible.

Comment: @RichardSmith thanx

Comment: That's not what the Host header is for! The Host header indicates the domain name in the URL that the client requested, e.g. `www.yandex.ru` or whatever.

Comment: @MichaelHampton anyway IIS looks on the Host header and then don't see known value in bindings and returns 400 invalid hostname. Documentation clarify meaning of host header https://httpwg.org/specs/rfc7230.html#header.host .